How to get bootchart (or bootchart2) working on system with dracut and efistub?
Im trying to minimize boottime as much as possible.
Currently im running Void Linux with an EFISTUB and dracut as the init manager.
I now want to utilize bootchart to check where i can improve, but I cant get it to work.
It seems that in older versions of dracut one could use
dracut -f -a bootchart to include the bootchart package and use  rdinit=/sbin/bootchartd to start it on boot, but dracut doesnt seem to have the bootchart module anymore.
